# Users can see other user's accounts

Tags: security, sharing

Users can now see all other user's accounts.  The default is private.
We recently added account teams, and I suspect this is the issue.

Can someone verify the following scenario?

I have user A, and user B.  A and B should not be able to see each others accounts.  I'm on the account team for all A's accounts, and all B's accounts.  since I'm shared on all accounts, does that allow A to see B's accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Account teams are to open up the sharing.

If your user `Lance Wentz` is added to Account team of Accounts owned by `A` and `B`, Only you would be able to access Accounts where you are added in Account Team based on the selected permission.

`A` and `B` would not be able to see each other's Account, unless specific access is granted via different sharing method like manual, Account team, etc.

---

**Summary by Sebastian Kessel:**

> In one word, the answer is NO. You being in the Account Teams does not
>   allow A and B to see each other.

Comment: Rahul, you explained beautifully (thus my upvote) but forgot to summarize the answer. In one word, the answer is NO. You being in the Account Teams does not allow A and B to see each other.

Comment: Hey thanks Sebastian, thanks for your help. Will add that to the answer! :)

Comment: Thanks guys.  What else could allow A to see B's accounts?

Comment: You should read sharing and security module in trailhead of in documentation. Best would be to actually try couple of things in your org by yourself. Option in can think of is sharing rules, manual sharing, account team, roles, apex sharing. Refer [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_data_access.htm&language=en_US&type=0) documentation for more details.